# Unable to Install Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, 10586, System Partition Encrypted w/ VeraCrypt

Tags: windows-10, encryption

I have a laptop running windows 10 Pro, The system drive has been encrypted with VeraCrypt.

I am unable to get the update 'Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, 10586' to install.  Each attempt at installing follows this path.

1. Prompted To Update
2. Give the OK to reboot
3. Presented with VeraCrypt Boot loader, Enter my decryption key
4. Booted into some sort of Windows Diagnostic mode, asking me for my keyboard language
5. Select English and I am presented with the option to boot back into Windows
6. Back to VeraCrypt Boot Loader, enter decryption key
7. Enter back into windows, update not applied.

Here is the error in the event viewer each time.

> Log Name: System Source: Windows UpdateClient EventID: 20 Installation
>   Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error
>   0x8024200D: Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, 10586.

I found this link, [Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, 10586 errors with 0x8024200D](https://superuser.com/questions/1000529/upgrade-to-windows-10-pro-version-1511-10586-errors-with-0x8024200d) and performed the highest rated answer, as well as the accepted answer.  The end result was the same.  The update attempted to install, I went through the reboot, and I ended up without the update installed.

Comment: You need to unencrypt the drive, install the update, then encrypt the drive.  This is we'll documented about FDE and upgrade process for Windows

Comment: Can you please provide this as an answer, so I can accept it?  As horrible as it is to have to decrypt, it worked.

Comment: Since I believe it to be a duplicate.  It already has an answer, DiskCryptor and VeraCrypt both are based on TrueCrypt, which also would have the same solution, not going to duplicate an existing answer.